# Помогите разобраться со знаками препинания, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со знаками препинания в предложении. Не могу понять, правильно ли расставила их и нужно ли тире между словами "кошек" и "особенно".

> Он любит кошек – всех животных, но кошек особенно – и работает
> волонтёром в приюте по соседству.

Comment: Я бы упростил, потому что не ясно, зачем такое накручено. Он очень любит кошек. Всех животных любит, но кошек особенно. Он работает волонтёром в приюте по соседству.

Comment: Да, надо менять, предложение неграмотное. Можно: *Он любит всех животных, особенно кошек, и работает волонтёром в приюте по соседству.*